# How to remove products from cart in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am writing code for removing product from cart but i am facing a few problems.First is when i click on remove the product is not deleted from cart and the second is that, in my urls.py, i have added regex on id for removing product from cart.But when i click on remove, the id isn't displayed in the url.

**Views.py**

```
def remove_from_cart(request,id):
try:
    the_id=request.session['cart_id']
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
except:
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
cartitem=CartItem.objects.get(id=id)

cartitem.cart=None
cartitem.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

**models.py**

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart=models.ForeignKey('Cart',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    accessory = models.ForeignKey(Accessories,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    line_total=models.DecimalField(default=10.99,max_digits=1000,decimal_places=2)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
   def __unicode__(self):
        try:
           return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.title
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^cart/(?P<id>\d+)/$', remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
```

**template.html**

```
<td><a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' item.id %}">Remove</a></td>
```

Please if any one can help it would be really appreciated?

**Note:** I have searched different links on stackoverflow but none helped.

Comment: can you please check if there is any cart_id in session?

Comment: Yes Sir as i have updated the cart using session.

Answer (score 0):

What query you send to template, can you provide it?

```
def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    card = Cart.objects.filter(id=the_id)
    if card.exists():
        cartitem = CartItem.objects.filter(card_id=card.first().id)
        if cartitem.exists():
            cartitem.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Marin Sir. But the problem is still there. It's not showing any error but the products are not removing.